# How do I create a new ASP.NET MVC website from template in Visual Web Developer 2008 Express?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-web-developer

I installed Visual Web Developer 2008 Express SP1 and then ASP.NET MVC 1.0, but when I go to File > New Website, ASP.NET MVC doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new Project, not a new Website. Go to File > New Project, under the Web project types you'll see ASP.NET MVC Web Application.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to here.

[ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/mvc/gallery/default.aspx?supportsjs=true)

Not really an answer to your question I guess but it does have MVC Site designs.